# How to save an embedded Word document in an Excel workbook as a separate file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a workbook that will populate an embedded Word document template with pictures, and then save the document elsewhere, without editing the embedded template. 
However, when I try to save the document, I get a Run-Time Error 4605 telling me:
"The SaveAs method or property is not available because this document is being edited in another applicator"

This is the sub to open the template:

```
Sub OpenWord()
'Opens the template when the main function first runs

    Set WDObj = Sheets("Template").OLEObjects("Template")

    WDObj.Activate
    WDObj.Object.Application.Visible = False

    Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    Set WDDoc = WDApp.ActiveDocument                   

End Sub
```

After this a main sub runs which populates the template, then when I try to save the document using:

```
WDDoc.SaveAs "myDocument.doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
```

I get the error.

Please has anyone encountered this error before/ know to to fix it, I have done much Googling which still has not gotten me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following, which worked on my system/installation:

```
Sub OpenWord()
'Opens the template when the main function first runs

    Dim WDObj As Object
    Dim WDApp As Object

    Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set WDObj = Sheets("Template").OLEObjects("Template")

    WDObj.Activate
    WDObj.Object.Application.Visible = False

    WDApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("YourFilename.doc")
    Set WDObj = Nothing
    Set WDApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried many iterations of this code and my own and still I get the same error. I think maybe it could be a specific problem with my system/ installation.

Comment: Reboot/restart your computer? (Full shut down, not hibernate and so)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still seeing the same error, I did think perhaps it is due to the fact I am still editing the document when I try to save it, but I don't see why that should cause any problems.

Comment: In my test the doument was embedded and shown as an icon. Maybe try that (in a clean workbook) as a test. I.e., try to get to a minimal situation where it works.